# How do I remember a word if it's too fancy to use and too rare to come across it very often?

Tags: discussion

Sorry if this site is not meant for such questions, it's not yet entirely clear to me what is and what's not. For example, lately, I came across the Latin expression 'bona fide'. I don't remember I've seen it before (so, I suppose, it's used relatively rarely) but if I do encounter it in speech or writing, I want to know what it means. All those word cards, notes — all that is crap, based on my experience, it's not working. I incorporate a new word into my vocabulary (my brain does) when I either see it often (at least, from time to time) or if I use it myself. You can't do the latter because it's too show-offy (it seems so to me, as most Latin phrases are). How can I learn it?

Comment: This might be a good Meta post. I think your question is "opinion-based", and so it might be off-topic for the main site. But in Meta, discussion is allowed and encouraged.

Comment: @AIQ Let's see if it helps